# Swift - launch-screen SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, runtime-error

just a real quick issue i'm having with my current swift project. Essentially; i'm trying to implement a combination of tutorials to present an animated launch screen for my application; but with the following code I'm getting an error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" which I can't seem to figure out the root cause for. The example project I was following was using a tableview as there main home screen with is the only difference between our projects; but I can't find a a justification in the code that would be responsible for proving my errors. The error resides somewhere within the following as my the remainder of my viewController's have been left blank to try and find the root of the problem.

Here's my app delegate file where the error resides
 import UIKit

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 196/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

            // rootViewController from StoryBoard
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

            // logo mask
            navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
            navigationController.view.layer.mask!.contents = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!.cgImage
            navigationController.view.layer.mask!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask!.position = CGPoint(x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)

            // logo mask background view
            let maskBgView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
            maskBgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBgView)
            navigationController.view.bringSubview(toFront: maskBgView)

            // logo mask animation
            let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
            transformAnimation.delegate = self as? CAAnimationDelegate
            transformAnimation.duration = 1
            transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1 //add delay of 1 second
            let initalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: (navigationController.view.layer.mask!.bounds))
            let secondBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            let finalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))
            transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
            transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
            transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)]
            transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            navigationController.view.layer.mask!.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")

            // logo mask background view animation
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1,
                           delay: 1.35,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                           animations: {
                            maskBgView.alpha = 0.0
            },
                           completion: { finished in
                            maskBgView.removeFromSuperview()
            })

            // root view animation
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 1.3,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                           animations: {
                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
            },
                           completion: { finished in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                                           delay: 0.0,
                                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                                           animations: {
                                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                            },
                                           completion: nil
                            )
            })

            return true

    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to your crash, but I remember calling `makeKeyAndVisible` **after** setting the root view controller in the pre-storyboard days... Just before `return true`.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to mention which line of code is causing the crash. Perhaps you should set `Exception` and `Swift Error` breakpoints.

Comment: Also, it seems very unorthodox to start your animations in the AppDelegate. I know you are setting delays > 1 second for them, but there might be some under-the-hood UIView-related work needed to set them up that just isn't ready until the view controller is actually displayed... **Just a wild guess**. Is it too difficult to setup your animations in the view controller's `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`?

Comment: Just debugged. Error messaged is being caused by:  let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

Comment: Is there anything printed in the log? You should see some kind of error message before the SIGABRT.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: `self.window!.` Can not be the cause (you are accessing it before); Obviously the instantiation from storyboard is not working. Use a `guard else` block, and also check your view controller's identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: You mention **"LaunchScreen"**. Any chance you are trying to attach logic to something you are not able to? LaunchScreen storyboards can't do anything like this. They are very "static".

Comment: Guard else block is showing that there is definitely something wrong with the identifier; but i've verified the storyboard over and over and i really don't understand what's not matching up.

Comment: Is it the same storyboard? Aren't you confusing Main and Launch storyboards? Did you try to instantiate the **initial** view controller (the one with an arrow to its left) instead of explicitly by id?

Comment: Did try; but still causing same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where your application might crash.

The first crash possibility is related to instantiating `UIViewController` from `Storyboard`. Instead of instantiating from Storyboard you can try some blank `UIViewController`:

```
let navigationController = UIViewController()
self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
```

If it doesn't crash then there are some issues with your `Main.storyboard`.

The second place that might cause a crash:

```
navigationController.view.layer.mask!.contents = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!.cgImage
```

Please make sure that your image is fine and it exists in the project.

Also, you might want to rethink you approach to optional values unwrapping. Use:

```
navigationController.view.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "logo.png")?.cgImage
```

Instead of:

```
navigationController.view.layer.mask!.contents = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!.cgImage
```

**Edit:**

I have caught your exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'navigationController''

Please make sure you have a `Storyboard ID` correctly specified for your `navigationController`.

[image]

If you need a hint how to catch exceptions, ask in comments.

Comment: changing the delegate code from what you suggested: let navigationController = UIViewController()
self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController didn't cause crashes. I really don't know what the issue is with my main.storyboard

Comment: @user3686630 I have added a screenshot, check it out.